# Could not find appropriate get method for private boolean in OrmLite

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I am using OrmLite in an Android application and am getting sporadic crashes with the following error. It looks like its complaining about not finding a getter method.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{com.app/com.app.MainActivity_}:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find appropriate get method for  private boolean com.app.model.User.isKeepAlive
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2760)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find appropriate get method for private boolean com.app.model.User.isKeepAlive
   at com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseFieldConfig.findGetMethod(DatabaseFieldConfig.java:548)
   at com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType.(FieldType.java:236)
   at com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTableConfig.convertFieldConfigs(DatabaseTableConfig.java:236)
   at com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTableConfig.extractFieldTypes(DatabaseTableConfig.java:101)
   at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.initialize(BaseDaoImpl.java:153)
   at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.(BaseDaoImpl.java:128)
   at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.(BaseDaoImpl.java:119)
   at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl$5.(BaseDaoImpl.java:921)
   at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.createDao(BaseDaoImpl.java:921)
   at com.j256.ormlite.dao.DaoManager.createDao(DaoManager.java:72)
   at com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.getDao(OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.java:279)
   at com.app.utility.DatabaseHelper.getUserDao(DatabaseHelper.java:126)
   at com.app.controller.UserController.getLoggedInUser(UserController.java:318)
   at com.app.controller.UserController.isLoggedIn(UserController.java:304)
```

The weird thing is I have a get method defined in my entity class as below:

```
@DatabaseField(useGetSet = true)
private boolean isKeepAlive;

/**
 * @return the isKeepAlive
 */
public boolean getIsKeepAlive() {
    return isKeepAlive;
}

/**
 * @param isKeepAliveSet the isKeepAliveSet to set
 */
public void setIsKeepAlive(boolean isKeepAlive) {
    this.isKeepAlive = isKeepAlive;
}
```

Comment: It's a little strange to have a boolean be `isKeepAlive`.  Typically the boolean is `keepAlive` and the _method_ is `isKeepAlive`.  That said I'm surprised that ORMLite doesn't handle it.

Comment: It might be a locale issue.  Trunk has a fix on it that does a better job of handling capitalization of method names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion @Gray. Updating my methods and using the latest from trunk seems to have resolved my issue.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but it could be. You should [edit] in the essential information of the answer so that future users can benefit from it. Comments are temporary and not indexed by search engines, so they aren't a great place for answers.